# FontAwesome for checkbox

Tags: html, css, checkbox, font-awesome

I am trying to use FontAwesome for checkbox - so in unchecked state - it will display [Trash](http://fontawesome.io/icon/trash-o/) icon, and in checked state, it will display the same icon but in red color.

I added the font-awesome.min.css and the fonts.

HTML:

```
<div class="delete-checkbox">
   <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-delete-6053923167078">
   <span></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.delete-checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}

.delete-checkbox span:before {
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    font-style: normal;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    content: '\f014';
    margin-right: .3em;
}

.delete-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ span:before {
    color: red;
}
```

I do see in the result the trash icon, however, it's not clickable and when I click on it, it doesn't turn red.

How can I do it?

Comment: You're using "display: none", which in essence removes the element from the dom.

Comment: correct, because i don't want the regular checkbox

Comment: It's not clear at all from your question, or the answer you marked as correct why you need jQuery for this - the HTML/CSS version works perfectly based on your question.

Comment: I marked the correct one.

Comment: Just for some inspiration. https://lokesh-coder.github.io/pretty-checkbox/

Comment: @lokesh-coder this looks like an amazing library. I would post it as an answer for future icon lookers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

http://jsbin.com/sanoya/edit?html,css,output

The problem is that when you use `display: none;` you are essentially removing the element from the DOM, and the element is therefore not clickable.

Comment: I don't want to have the regular checkbox - I want to use the image as a checkbox

Comment: What's wrong with the jsbin I posted? It shows only the trash icon, and when the input is checked the icon turns red.

Comment: it doesn't show the trash icon - I am using chrome - it shows a black rectangle. When I click on it it turns red, but the image is not being displayed instead of it

Comment: that's because the font is missing.. put it in your code, it will work perfectly, with no javascript required.

Comment: Glad to hear it.. and you will be able to have many elements on the page without issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript if you like

Replace your `<span></span>` with the following:

```
<span onclick="document.getElementById('checkbox-delete-6053923167078').checked = !document.getElementById('checkbox-delete-6053923167078').checked"></span>
```

Or, if you are using jQuery, you can use this:

```
<span onclick="$('#checkbox-delete-6053923167078').prop('checked', !$('#checkbox-delete-6053923167078').prop('checked'));"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks. that's the correct answer. I will tick when I can in a few moments!

Comment: Just added non-jquery version too :)

Comment: I preferred to go for a pure CSS solution, but thanks!

Comment: Yes, I think @Toby's solution is nicer

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use JavaScript to achieve what you're looking for. Your markup was almost fine. You should use a `<label>` tag, instead of a `<span>` tag and also, you should have used `<label>` in your CSS. Doing so, you would have end up with a markup like this

```
<div class="delete-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-delete-6053923167078">
  <label for="checkbox-delete-6053923167078"></label>
</div>
```

and with CSS like this

```
.delete-checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

.delete-checkbox label:before {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-style: normal;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  content: '\f014';
  margin-right: .3em;
}

.delete-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label:before {
  color: red;
}
```

As you can see, I've only changed your `<span>` with the `<label>` tag.

With this, you are totally able to do what you're looking for, without using and JavaScript code.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/otcjqt8w/)

Comment: can I remove the label if I don't need to write anything next to the checkbox?

Comment: The label provides functionallity to check a checkbox. Since you display out the checkbox itself you need sonething to trigger a click on. In this case, the label itself is empty and get its content through css. If you remove the label, you need to display the checkbox itself.